# I want to create a Pivot table in SQL as mentioned in the screenshot

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, aggregate-functions

[image]]

In the image, we have a table and we are supposed to use PIVOT functions in SQL to obtain the exact output shown below the original table. I have tried it but not able to get it. Can someone please help!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select name,
    max(case when grade = 1 then marks end) as grade1,
    max(case when grade = 2 then marks end) as grade2,
    max(case when grade = 3 then marks end) as grade3
from mytable
group by name
```